# Pygame sprite double jump

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm relatively new to pygame, and have started to branch off from a basic tutorial. I want the sprite to be able to double jump and have attempted to add in a variable etc so I can change it to a triple jump if they eventually gain a power up or some sort, and I can change it easily, but I'm struggling. P.S: Some of the comments might not make sense as some code has been removed, but are still useful to me.

```
x = 200
y = 450
width = 64
height = 66
vel = 5
screenwidth = 500
isjump = True #whether our character is jumping or not
jumpcount = 10
maxjump = 2 #double jump
maxjumpcount = 0

#we must keep track of direction, are they moving and how many steps for frames

left = False
right = False
walkcount = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkcount

    window.blit(background,(0,0)) #loads bg at 0,0

    if  walkcount +1 >= 15: #15 as we have 5 sprites, which will be displayed 3 times per second
        walkcount = 0

    if left:
        window.blit(walkleft[walkcount//3],(x,y))#excludes remainders
        walkcount+=1
    elif right:
        window.blit(walkright[walkcount//3],(x,y))
        walkcount+=1
    elif isjump:
        window.blit(jumpp,(x,y))
        walkcount+=1
    else:
        window.blit(char,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()


#now to write main loop which checks for collisions, mouse events etc
run = True
while run: #as soon as we exit this, the game ends
    #main loop, gonna check for collision

    clock.tick(15) #frame rate, how many pics per second, games r just a ton of pictures running very quickly
    #now we check for events

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #gets a list of all events that happened
        print(event)
                                    #can go through these events& check if they've happened
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if we try to exit the window
            run = False

   through the use of events. If a key has been pressed, we change the x & y of our shape
    #if we want it to continuely move, we need to get a list



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #if these are pressed or held down, execute whatever is under these.


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel-vel: #if pressed we move our character by the velocity in whatever direction via grid which works from the TOP LEFT of screen
        #0,0 is top left           #vel-vel to equal 0, makes border better
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < screenwidth - width: #as the square co ord is top left of it
        x+= vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkcount = 0

   #JUMP CODE
    if not(isjump): # still lets them move left and right
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True #quadratic function for jump
            right = False
            left = False
            walkcount = 0
            maxjumpcount+=1
            if maxjumpcount > 2:
                isjump = False
    else:
        while jumpcount >= -10 and maxjumpcount < 2: #moving slower, then faster, hang, then go down
            pygame.time.delay(12)
            y -= (jumpcount*abs(jumpcount)) / 2#1.35? #squared, 10 ^2, /2, jumpcount = jump height
            jumpcount -= 1


        else: #jump has concluded if it reaches here
            isjump = False
            jumpcount = 10
            maxjumpcount = 0 #double jump resets once jump ends

    redrawGameWindow()
```

Apologies for quite a pathetic attempt. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I still have so much to learn. Thanks.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion - what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error/exception? If not what is happening vs what do you want/expect to happen?

Comment: The jump code I used wasn't really suitable for my intention. I solved it by using a variable which limits the user to how many times they can press space & jump until they touch the floor again, and had to completely re-do the jump function. Thank you, though, I'll work on my clarity next post.

Answer (score 2):

You have a game loop, use it. You don't need an extra loop for the jump. Use a selection (`if`) instead of the inner `while` loop, to solve the issue:

```py
run = True
while run: #as soon as we exit this, the game ends
    # [...]

    if not(isjump): # still lets them move left and right
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            # [...]
    else:

        # instead of: while jumpcount >= -10 and maxjumpcount < 2: 
        if jumpcount >= -10 and maxjumpcount < 2: # <---------------

            y -= (jumpcount*abs(jumpcount)) / 2
            jumpcount -= 1
```

Note, this block of code is continuously called in the main application loop.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, have changed it.